# Need help for my rwd theme development

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, rwd, rwd-theme

I have just installed magento 1.9 for my store, and I am now trying to make a custom theme...

I would like to use the new RWD theme option for tablets/smartphones best compatibility.

I then read the knowledge base document called "Magento CE 1.9 and EE 1.14 Responsive Web Design Developer's Guide" and started the different steps :
- Ruby, compass and cass installed on my computer
- Magento cache disabled on my store on my web host
- Copying files to create a custom theme (both on my local computer and on my web host)
(all the steps were passed successfully)

But now, I am a bit lost on what to do…

First questions : If I understand correctly, I must modify the files locally, compiled them with compass and then reload them on my web host? I am right?

Second question : In the file copying process of the knowledge base document, not all the files of the default theme are copied. I then think some of the default theme files are still used if not redefined in the new theme? I am right?

I would like to first change the structural blocks of the store…

I would like the header, the left, the content and the footer block (no right block). 
Where / How can I Modify this?

Where / how can I modify the content block to structural block mapping?

Sorry for all these questions and thank you for your help,

Answer (score 1):

I can help with some of your questions:

- #1, yes, copy the compiled CSS to your server after doing your development locally.
- #2, I don't have the expertise to answer your question fully. However, Alan Storm explains fallback in his article: http://alanstorm.com/magento_parent_child_themes

I hope this answers some of your concerns.